# Local register of a group leader

Tags: erlang, local, leader

I try to register group_leader() locally using

```
register( iogl, group_leader()).
```

but it returns with bad_arg error

```
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  register/2
    called as register(iogl,<0.29.0>)
```

**How can i give a local symbolic name to the  group_leader() process?**

I do able to register it as a global name using

```
global:register_name(iogl, group_leader()).
```

but its not what I need.

**UPD:** The real problem:

I create process on remote node (**RN**) using spawn from local node(**LN**), but i want that process to use  group_leader of **RN** , not **LN** for io operations.
Thank you.

Comment: What's the point of registering the group leader against a name when everywhere else you could just call `group_leader()` instead?

Comment: actually I have another problem and this is my work around, (which doesn't work). I updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is for the code you spawn on the remote node to do:

```
io:format(user, FormatString, FormatArguments)
```

This will cause the remote code to use the remote IO group leader for output. You could also have the code you spawn remotely to set its group_leader to the pid of `user` shortly after it is spawned, it could then use `io:format/2` normally and it will send its output to the correct place on the remote node.

I guess the short answer is that the registered(symbolic) name for the standard group leader process on any node is `user`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How simple was it! group leader is already have a local registered name: 'user' :). Thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes, I really, really, dislike Erlang.  In particular, because things like this are counter intuitive, undocumented and make perfect sense once someone explains them.  For the next person who finds this, run this to change the group leader to that of the node the code is running on: group_leader(whereis(user), self()).

Comment: At least they make sense once explained :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can register it, the group_leader is a pid like any pid. There are two reasons that you get the error:

- That name is already registered.
- The process is already dead, there is no checking that the group_leader process is alive.

And I repeat @OJ's question of why you would want to give it a name.

Comment: If name is already registered or process dead, how can global register succeed?

Comment: But my real problem is different: I create process on remote node using spawn, but i what that process to use group_leader of remote node for io, (not the node from which it has been spawned)

Answer (score 1):

To spawn **at** remote node would help.
You need some spawner process at each node, just like standard rpc module does.

Couudant's rexi library implements such functions.
https://github.com/cloudant/rexi
See rexi:cast/3:

```
rexi:cast(remote_node, self(), {io, format, ["~p~n", ["where to go the output?"]]}).
```